# Science fiction movie about a mystery spaceship which can be alive

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember a movie that was on TV a few times when I was a teenager. I just can't seem to find it anymore on any of the lists of sci-fi movies from the 60's, 70's, 80's. Maybe anyone here can help.

Some things I think I can remember :

- The plot revolved around an immense spaceship.
- It has no inhabitants except some kind of lunatic man / captain.
- A few persons come aboard this ship. Maybe as a result of a catastrophe on their own ship or because they where sent there
- It seemed as if the ship was "alive". Either it was this man who had his own persona fused with the ship or it was his mother... there was something with his mother if I remember.
- I recall scene's of gigantic hallways inside the ship, very light and bright, meant to be very impressive.
- The film was presented on TV as a sci-fi masterpiece but since I can't seem to find it on any of the "top 100 sci fi" lists this may have been an overestimation of the time.
- I think it was around 1985-1990 that I was it on TV in the Netherlands. That would give you a clue as to the release date. I don't think it's anything post 1985.
- English language... almost certainly American / Holywood made.

Hope anyone here can remember.

Comment: The part where only the captain is on board reminds me of the Disney movie "The Black Hole". But the ship was rather dark... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole

Comment: The part with the ship alive / personality is the one thing that kicks out The Black Hole for me. The ship was lit excessively when the Palomino approached, and the hallways also.

Comment: Not great matches, but https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3 or possibly https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(1972_film) (although it would take some doing to sit through the latter several times - great film, but long and slow-paces!)

Comment: Event Horizon. But you need a time machine for that.

Comment: It sounds exactly like Event Horizon, save for the release date. Maybe check out that film and see if you were wrong about the release date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I offer [NIghtflyers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5k6jfqcXxc) as a possible answer. Been a few years since I saw it, but it has the following:

1. Oddball captain seemingly wired into the ship
2. The ghost of his "mother" possessing the ship
3. A group of people that come aboard to go on a mission.
4. Released in 1987, so it is the right time frame.

I cannot find the movie online, but the link below goes to the trailer, so I cannot validate the "bright hallway" aspect.

Most assuredly not a sci-fi masterpiece, but still interesting as a "haunted house in space" movie.

Comment: Nice find, the movie is based on a shortstory by George R. R. Martin (author of A Song of Ice and Fire aka Game of Thrones).

Comment: Thuis must be the movie that i was looking for. Thanks. Jealousy between the mother and someone in the crew also matches. The captain only showing himself through holograms is another match. It is a lot more focussed on horror and action than i remember though. Anyway, thanks again.